# Labels and Radio Buttons slightly misaligned, how to fix?

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to coding and currently working on a responsive web design certification. I'm in the middle of a project to create a survey form with basic HTML and CSS and have to implement a radio section.

The problem is the radio input and the labels are just slightly misaligned and its been driving me insane. I can get them to look like they are in-line by adjusting the height of the radio buttons but its never quite right. I've tried padding, margins, line-height, and extensive googling all to no avail. I even attempted to switch to css grid but that just brought up more problems. I'm sure the solution is extremely simple and I will be mad, but please help a budding coder out :)

Here is the link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/melv1ns/pen/NWNRBrB

Html:

```
<p id = "radio-question">Would you recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</p>
    <div id= "radio-container">
      <label for = "definitely" class = "radio-labels">
        <input  id = "definitely" type = "radio" name = "recommend" class = "radio"> Definitely </label>
      
      <label for = "maybe" class = "radio-labels">
        <input  id = " maybe" type = "radio" name = "recommend" class = "radio"> Maybe</label>
      
      <label for = "not-sure" class = "radio-labels"> 
        <input  id = "not-sure" type = "radio" name = "recommend" class = "radio"> Not Sure</label>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
input{
  width: 90%;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#radio-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

.radio-labels{
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

input[type = "radio"]{
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#radio-question{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**slightly misaligned radio button and their labels**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead,

remove `padding-bottom;`

```
.radio-labels{
  padding-bottom:2px;
}
```

Add this style

```
input[type = "radio"]{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```css
input{
  width: 90%;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#radio-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

.radio-labels{
  height: auto;
}

input[type = "radio"]{
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#radio-question{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p id = "radio-question">Would you recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</p>
    <div id= "radio-container">
      <label for = "definitely" class = "radio-labels">
        <input  id = "definitely" type = "radio" name = "recommend" class = "radio"> Definitely </label>
      
      <label for = "maybe" class = "radio-labels">
        <input  id = " maybe" type = "radio" name = "recommend" class = "radio"> Maybe</label>
      
      <label for = "not-sure" class = "radio-labels"> 
        <input  id = "not-sure" type = "radio" name = "recommend" class = "radio"> Not Sure</label>
    </div>
```